# How can you create an app that accesses a local database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, xamarin

I am a programmer who has a desktop program developed on Vb.net. This program works under Windows with a local Access database. Now what I need is to add functions to query and update the database but from a mobile device (Android and IOS). I understand that the most correct way is to develop a program in Xamarin, but I do not know very well how to access the customer's data. I have little experience with mobile devices and I do not know how to approach the project. I know this is a very generic question, but perhaps someone with more experience in this field could give me a vision on how to approach the project.

The final result will be to access local data from a mobile app

Comment: I know this is a generic question, but any suggestion is welcome. thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest you make a WEB-API that acts as the bridge between the mobile device and the Database, Not a big fan of direct DB connections!!

Comment: Also after further reading your post, I read you talk about a local database but in your scenario, the local database for a Xamarin app is the mobile database and the one outside of the mobile is a remote database no matter where it is

Comment: Yes @G.hakim is right, it's not a good practice that a client accesses a database directly, and as G.hakim said you're better off make a web server so that the client(mobile app) use CRUD functions database through web APIs.

Comment: The first thing you'll need to do is ditch the Access database and migrate the data to a proper SQL Server which can be hosted on a server, so that multiple devices can have access to it. Trying to connect from a mobile device to an Access database on a local disk of a user's PC is not going to work. Then yes as others have said the conventional architecture is to use a Web API on the server as well, which provides security/authentication and business logic, and manages the interaction with the database (i.e. it runs all the queries)....

Comment: ... The mobile app then makes HTTP requests to the API to send and receive data. You could consider also refactoring your desktop app to do the same - i.e. it doesn't contain much business logic itself (only enough to display the right things on screen at the right time), and uses the API to send and receive data and do the major processing / business logic. That way you can share this code between all your frontend applications without having to maintain multiple versions.

Comment: Thanks. which are CRUD functions?? My application is to manage a company, enter customer and supplier invoices, expirations, ... then manage a high volume of information. How can I send and receive all the information on a server reliably?

Comment: CRUD (as you'll discover if you google it!) stands for "create, read, update, delete". It's just a shorthand for the very standard functionality you often find provided through a programming interface, where you can manipulate particular objects through these simple operations.

Comment: As for "reliably"...I don't know what specifically you want to talk about here. There could be many meanings to that. It's a fairly big software / technical architecture piece of work to make your application "reliable" in every sense. Do you have a particular concern about it?